# Sequelize - Check if any strings in array contain a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Right now, my model has field with an array of words e.g. a row has this field set to ['tag1', 'tag2', 'pineapple']

Now say someone searches for 'pine' or 'tag'. I want to return all instances/rows which have a string in that array that contains or is equal to that search term?

Therefore, that row should be returned as it matches 'pine' in 'pineapple'. Therefore, I want to do [Op.contains] but also get inexact matches. I use pgSQL in production if that helps.

Comment: You want to know if any string of the array contains the test-string complete or as part and want to return than the whole array othewise an empty array?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but what I want to do is run a Sequelize query like Model.findAll...bla bla where field 'tags' (an array field) contains a string inside that contains or is equal to target string? Is this clearer

Comment: Not complete. It would be easier if you give me a concrete example (preferably in the question because of formatting) what's your model like and what the desired output should be.

Answer (score 1):

I use Sequelize V6 and I have a similar issue where I have an array of strings and I want to find a record that contains one of the strings or more than one of the strings or even a character of some string in that array, so I ended up doing it like this:

```js
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

let strings = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'pineapple'];

let addedLikeOperator = strings.map((word) => ({ [Op.iLike]: `%${word || ""}%` })) //this line will add iLike operator for each string

tags.findAll({
      where: {
        tagName: {
          [Op.and]: addedLikeOperator,
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. I look if any string of the array contains the test-string complete or as part and return than the whole array otherwise an empty array.
For this I look with array.some if there is at least 1 array-element which contains at any position the test-string. If so I return the complete array otherwise an empty one.

```js
 let array = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'pineapple'];
 
 function strContained(str, array) {
     return (array.some(elem => elem.indexOf(str)!=-1)) ? array : [];
 };
 

 console.log(strContained('pine', array));
 console.log(strContained('pines', array));
 console.log(strContained('tag1', array));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but what I want to do is run a Sequelize query like Model.findAll...bla bla where field 'tags' (an array field) contains a string inside that contains or is equal to target string? Is this clearer